# Recovering data with a mouse when the screen doesn't respond to touch

Tags: data-recovery, broken-screen, touchscreen, touch

Suppose my screen breaks, and I can no longer operate it via touch, but I can still see parts of the screen although broken.

In this case, can I connect to my Android device via a mouse (for instance, a Bluetooth mouse, or a mouse via USB hub that allows me to charge my phone or keep it charged while keeping a USB mouse attached simultaneously)?

This way I could back up some pictures that were not saved to Google photos, WhatsApp chats, or other data.

So, this could be useful (navigating with a mouse when your screen is broken and does not respond to touch).

Is Android configured by default to support this behavior? If not, then i think it should. I don't know which screens break the touch sensor only when they break, but perhaps quite a few. In this case, if Android is not preconfigured to allow this behavior, the mouse will not be able to operate, and the data will be unrecoverable.

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Yes, most devices allow an external mouse. Note that if touch doesn't work you won't be able to pair a Bluetooth mouse or enable Bluetooth if disabled, so for starting you need an USB mouse or keyboard plus adapter and hopefully your phone supports USB OTG so that USB devices work.

Comment: I think the question is about OTG charging simultaniously - not working on most devices